# Missing Option for Android Bundle In Android Studio

Tags: android, c++, android-studio, apk, android-app-bundle

My Android Studio does not give me the option to “Generate Signed Bundles”, it only allows me to “Generate Signed APK.” Additionally, the “Build Bundles/APKs” (or similar) is not existent. Even when I go through with Signed APK, no signed apk is outputted, nothing seems to happen.
I’m working with a developer for an android apk, so once I receive APK, I load it into Android Studio via “Profile or Debug APK.” I’m not sure if this is the problem.

When I go to the build variant tab, there is no module or variant present there, not sure why. When I go to project structure, it says the libraries folder is completely excluded, again, not sure why.

I have tried everything I can think of and have researched a ton to no avail.
Developer doesn’t use android studio either so they aren’t too sure on troubleshooting steps within this application.

Attached are some screenshots.

Image of Build Tab:

[image: Image of Build Tab]

Image of Build Output Console:

[image: Image of Build Output Console]

Comment: What version of Android Studio are you using?

Comment: I am using Chipmunk | 2021.2.1. 
When importing an APK for profiling or debug, it is missing gradle build, build variants, etc.
I think this is why it can't finish generating a signed APK nor compile any bundles.
I had begun tinkering with importing gradles from other projects, trying to add modules and new variants and was getting closer but was far too messy.
I ended up using a third party apk to aab converter and then using jarsigner. 
Would love to get this sorted and understand what I am doing wrong or if that is just the nature of the scenario.

Comment: You can only generate AABs from source.

Comment: That is what I was beginning to conclude. Thank you for clarifying.